# Laravel: set dependecy injection for Service like Controller

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have this code in my CompanyController

```
use App\Services\CompanyService;

public function store(CompanyService $companyService) {

    $result = $companyService->store();

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

And this code in my CompanyService

```
use stdClass;
use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

public function store(Request $request, Company $company) {

    // this also not work
    dd($request->all());

    $data = new stdClass;
    $data->status = 1;
    $data->message = 'success';

    return $data;
}
```

When i run this code, Laravel show error

> Too few arguments to function App\Services\CompanyService::store()  0
>   passed but exactly 1 expected

I know that **type hint dependecy injection** issue, because it work in Controllers but not work in my CompanyService when i call store() without params

How can i fix this and make it work in my CompanyService ?

Comment: In your service class you are taking two parameters public function store(Request $request, Company $company) : one is request and other is compny object

Comment: And you are calling it without any parameter    $result = $companyService->store();

Comment: i know this, because i want to Request $request, Company $company will default set in function parameters, like Laravel Controller set it with type hint dependency injection, i need to do this

Answer (score 1):

## **Edit:**

You can use `call()` method of `service container`
In your case:

```php
public function store()
    {
        $companyService = app(CompanyService::class);

        $result = $companyService->call('store');

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

<strike>Unfortunately it's not possible to method inject dependencies but you can inject your dependencies in your `construct` method, so in your case it would be like this:</strike>

```php
use stdClass;
use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Foo
{
    protected $request;

    protected $company;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Company $company)
    {
        $this->request = $request;

        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function store()
    {

        // this works
        dd($this->request->all());
        // Also injected
        dd($this->company);

        $data = new stdClass;
        $data->status = 1;
        $data->message = 'success';

        return $data;
    }
}
```

<strike>PS:
I believe laravel handles method injection in one of it's middlewares so as far as I know there is not possible way to perform method injection you can read about [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container</strike) for more info</strike>

Comment: thanks, i do like that in costructor, first i think this is not good idea